# MySQL join & search

Tags: mysql, join

I have a problem with joining some tables, heres my structure:

```
tbl_imdb:
fldID   fldTitle    fldImdbID
1       Moviename   0000001

tbl_genres:
fldID   fldGenre
1       Action
2       Drama

tbl_genres_rel:
fldID   fldMovieID  fldGenreID
1       1           1
2       1           2
```

What I’m trying to do is a query that will find all movies that is both an action movie and drama, is this possible to do without a subquery, if so, how?

What I'm trying right now is:

```
SELECT tbl_imdb.*
FROM tbl_imdb
LEFT JOIN tbl_imdb_genres_rel ON ( tbl_imdb.fldID = tbl_imdb_genres_rel.fldMovieID ) 
LEFT JOIN tbl_imdb_genres ON ( tbl_imdb_genres_rel.fldGenreID = tbl_imdb_genres.fldID ) 
WHERE tbl_imdb_genres.fldGenre =  'Drama'
AND tbl_imdb_genres.fldGenre =  'Action';
```

But this dosnt work, however it does work if I only keep one of the two WHERE's, but thats not what I want.

Comment: Your post says "action" but your query says "crime". Which is it?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it to Action now, my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do it:

## 1

```
SELECT     tbl_imdb.*
FROM       tbl_imdb
INNER JOIN tbl_genres_rel            rel_action  
ON         tbl_imdb.fldID          = rel_action.fldMovieID 
INNER JOIN tbl_genres                genre_action
ON         rel_action.fldGenreId   = genre_action.fldID 
AND        'Action'                = genre_action.fldGenre
INNER JOIN tbl_genres_rel            rel_drama  
ON         tbl_imdb.fldID          = rel_drama.fldMovieID 
INNER JOIN tbl_genres                genre_drama
ON         rel_drama.fldGenreId    = genre_drama.fldID 
AND        'Drama'                 = genre_drama.fldGenre
```

This method is on the same path as your original solution. 2 differences:

1. The join should be inner, not left because you're trying to get movies that certainly have the corresponding genre entry
2. Since you want to find 2 different generes, you'll have to do the join with tbl_genres_rel and tbl_genres twice, once for each particular genre you're interested in.

## 2

```
SELECT     tbl_imdb.*
FROM       tbl_imdb
INNER JOIN tbl_genres_rel              
ON         tbl_imdb.fldID            = tbl_genres_rel.fldMovieID 
INNER JOIN tbl_genres                
ON         tbl_genres_rel.fldGenreId = tbl_genres.fldID 
AND        tbl_genres.fldGenre      IN ('Action', 'Drama')
GROUP BY   tbl_imdb.fldID
HAVING     COUNT(*) = 2
```

Again, the basic join plan is the same. Difference here is that we join to the tbl_genres_rel and tbl_genres path just once. This on itself fetches all genres for one film, and then filters for the one's you're interested in. The ones that qualify will now have 2 rows for each distinct value of tbl_imdb.fldId. The GROUP BY aggregates on that, flattening that into one row. By asserting in the `HAVING` clause that we have exactly 2 rows, we ensure that we keep only those rows that have both the genres.

(Note that this assumes that there is a unique constraint on tbl_genres_rel over {fldMovieID, fldGenreID}. If such a constraint is not present, you should consider adding it.)

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT JOIN` is not applicable in your case because records should exist on both tables. And you need to `count` the instances of the movie

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tbl_imdb a 
            INNER JOIN tbl_genres_rel b
                on a.fldID = fldMovieID
            INNER JOIN tbl_genres c
                on c.fldGenreID = b.fldID
WHERE   c.fldGenre IN ('Drama', 'Action')
GROUP BY a.Moviename
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```